# Compile or Export a Coded Form

Tags: vb.net, forms, compilation, export

How can i export or compile a form that i make with code within a running application in VB.NET?

I'm making a simple form making application, i've got almost everything covered, with creating the new form and adding controls and stuff.

Example: create a new form with clicking a button:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
                Dim NewForm As New Form
                NewForm.Name = "Form1"
                NewForm.Text = "Form1"
                NewForm.Width = 300
                NewForm.Height = 300
                NewForm.Show()
        End Sub
```

How do i export or compile the new form to a standalone exe?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own file format (XML?) that describes the contents of the form.
Then, create a separate application that reads these files and display a form based on the file that it read.

If you want to ship single EXEs, you could embed the file as a resource in the launcher application and modify that resource to save custom EXEs.

---

Alternatively, you could use Roslyn or Mono Cecil or Expression trees to actually compile that code at runtime into a new EXE; that may be harder.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and for the idea. sorry for being a noob, but would something like Form1.Designer.vb work thats automatically generated when you create a new form?

Comment: @NetInfo: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: when you create a new form in vb, a file is automatically generated called something like Form1.Designer.vb, which contains code that describes the form. what im asking is should i create something like that for the new form, and make an application that reads that? thanks again.

Comment: @NetInfo: No; you should create your own format.  There is no point in writing a parser for that.